# check for number of breaklines and sometimes too many breaklines and replace it with only a full stop

Tags: java

I would like to replace the string that contains breaklines and replace it with ".". However, in order to replace it, my method is to check how many breaklines it has and then perform replacing. This will make it add too many ".". Example

```
st = "I have something nice \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n there"

    String st = st.replace('\r', ' ').replace('\n\n\n', '.').replace('\n', '.').replace('\n\n', '.').replace('\n\n\n\n', '.');
```

My current way if I keep adding toooooo many replace then it will be: (Is there a smarter way to do so?)

I have something nice ........... there

My expected output:

I have something nice . there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

`st.replaceAll("(?:\\s*\n)+", ".");`

`\\s*\n` will escape all endlines which can be followed by spaces.

Also it will eliminate the space between the last char and the "." which is ponctuation rule.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple regex to replace all occurrences at one:

```
String st = "I have something nice \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n there";
String replaceAll = st.replaceAll("\n+", ".");
```

Outputs:

```
I have something nice . there
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost forgot about replaceALl

Comment: There is a problem. I still getting many ................ when I have many  \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n. Any workaround to have only single . and not every one of the \n?

Comment: @slackking What is your exact command that produces this result?

Comment: I used .replaceAll('\n+', '.') but somehow when I include more "\n" into the string, I get a lot of "." and it increases according to the number of "\n" I put into the string.

Comment: you should use `.replaceAll("\n+", ".")`, not `.replaceAll('\n', '.')`

Comment: sorry, I meant with the + as well. its typo

Comment: Are you really using single quotes `'`? I'm sure this doesn't compile...

Comment: Actually, I am writing it in apex but since it has the same function for replaceAll with JAva so I put the tag as java here. So the single quotes can be compiled.

Comment: Maybe you have something else between your `\n`s as Spara suggests

Answer (score 1):

Use [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with regex:

```
String st = "I have something nice \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n there";

st = st.replaceAll("\n+", "."); // \n+ matches one or mutiple line breaks
System.out.println(st);//I have something nice . there
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgotten about the replaceAll.

Comment: There is a problem. I still getting many ................ when I have many  \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n. Any workaround to have only single . and not every one of the \n?

Comment: Try `st.replaceAll("\n+", ".")`, instead `st.replaceAll("\n", ".")`

Comment: I suggest to copy my code and compare it with yours to find the difference.